# Retrieve value from the closest available date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a system which stores the history of a balance in a history table.
The table has the account number, sort code, balance, balance start date, balance end date.
When a balance is updated an entry is created in the history table which shows what the balance, what the date was when that balance first started and the date which shows when the balances changed.  So for example the table will show a balance of $100.00 and this balance ran from 07/10/2013 to 07/15/2013.

**What I'm trying to do is get the sum of the balances for all sort codes on a specific day however the balance may not have changed on this date so I would need to return the closest prior date but I'm failing.**

This is what I tried so far.

```
declare @sdate datetime
set @sdate = '06/08/2012' --mm/dd/yyyy

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),MAX(StartDate),103) as "Closest Start Date",  Sort, SUM(Balance) AS "Sum of balances"
    FROM BalanceHistory
        WHERE StartDate <= convert(smalldatetime ,@sdate) AND SortCode <> 'ABC123456'
            GROUP BY SortCode
```

SELECT FROM BalanceHistory would produce something like

```
AccountNumber, SortCode, Balance, StartDate, EndDate, RECID
00000001, srt010203, 100.00, 06/01/2013, 06/02/2013,  RECID
00000001, srt010203, 110.00, 06/02/2013, 06/03/2013,  RECID
00000001, srt010203, 120.00, 06/03/2013, 06/04/2013,  RECID
00000002, srt010204, 200.00, 06/01/2013, 06/02/2013,  RECID
00000003, srt010204, 300.00, 06/01/2013, 06/02/2013,  RECID
00000004, srt010205, 400.00, 06/01/2013, 06/02/2013,  RECID
00000005, srt010205, 500.00, 06/01/2013, 06/02/2013,  RECID
```

Comment: What would your desired output look like given the sample table above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without a `JOIN` by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function (assuming SQL Server 2005 or newer):

```
DECLARE @sdate DATE
SET @sdate = '2012-06-08'
SELECT SortCode, SUM(Balance)'Sum of Balances'
FROM (SELECT AccountNumber,SortCode, Balance,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY StartDate DESC)'RowRank'
        FROM BalanceHistory
        WHERE StartDate <= @sdate AND SortCode <> 'ABC123456'
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
GROUP BY SortCode
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab8ef8/5/0)

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function in the subquery assigns a 'RowRank' to the balance for each accountnumber, we order by StartDate DESC to get rank of '1' for the most recent balance for each accountnumber, the WHERE criteria limits it to most recent balance from the date you set in your variable.  Then you use that rank in the outer query to limit only to that one balance.

Comment: The table is made up of:
Account Number, Sort Code, Balance, Start Date, End Date

I'm trying to get the sum of all the balances for each existing sort code on a specific date (or the closest date to it)... but I'm stumped because the balance history may not have changed on that day so I would need to check the closest available date entry to it.  For example if I want to see the balance sum on the 1st of July but the balance hasn't been updated since the 15th of June or some other date.

Comment: 1 account can have 1 sort code but 1 sort code can have many accounts.  1 balance per account.  ... Unless you mean on this table.  The history table creates a new row for each balance update so it shows historic stuff too so this table can hold multple balances per account but I am only interest in the closest to the specified date.

Comment: Sorry for screwing you around... I wasn't quite sure what you needed exactly.

Comment: Updated the main post to give you a better example

Comment: Updated answer, had missed syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Declare @table as table
(AccountNo int,
 Balance money,
 DateEntered datetime)

 Declare @dt datetime

 set @dt = '2013-07-01'
 Insert into @table values(1, 100, '2013-04-01')
Insert into @table values(2, 200, '2013-04-01')
Insert into @table values(2, 300, '2013-05-01')
Insert into @table values(2, 400, '2013-06-01')
  --select AccountNo, Max(Balance), Max(DateEntered) MaxDateEntered From @table where DateEntered <= @dt  group by AccountNo 


Select Sum(t.Balance) From @table t
inner join (select AccountNo, Max(Balance) Balance, Max(DateEntered) MaxDateEntered From @table where DateEntered <= @dt  group by AccountNo) tm
on t.AccountNo = tm.AccountNo and t.DateEntered = tm.MaxDateEntered

    enter code here
```